# Function to check if characters of a string are in a specific form

Tags: c, string

I want to check if the characters of a string are in this form:

`hw:` + one numeric character + `,` + one numeric character

```
hw:0,0 
hw:1,0
hw:1,1
hw:0,2

Et cetera

/* 'hw:' + 'one numeric character' + ',' + 'one numeric character' */
```

I found `strncmp(arg, "hw:", 3)` but that only checks the first 3 characters.

Comment: For just 6 chars like that it's fairly trivial to just check every character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tempting to use `strlen()` and `sscanf()`:

```
char *data = "hw:1,2";
char digit1[2];
char digit2[2];

if (strlen(data) == 6 && sscanf(data, "hw:%1[0-9],%1[0-9]", digit1, digit2) == 2)
    ...then the data is correctly formatted...
    ...and digit1[0] contains the first digit, and digit2[0] the second...
```

This works particularly well if you need to know what the two digits are, not merely that the format is correct.  However, you can also pull the digits out by fixed position, so that is not crucial.  It also upgrades gracefully (though not without change) if you need to allow for `"hw:12,25"` in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`strncmp(arg, "hw:", 3)` is a good start (remember that the function returns zero when the match is found). Next, you need to check that

- character 3 is a digit,
- character 4 is a comma, and
- character 5 is a digit.

This results in the following expression:

```
if (!strncmp(arg, "hw:", 3) && isdigit(arg[3]) && arg[4] == ',' && isdigit(arg[5])) {
    ...
}
```

Note the use of [`isdigit(int)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/isdigit.html) to test that a character is a digit.

If the numbers could span more than a single digit, you could use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf): this would also let you retrieve the values:

```
int a, b;
if (sscanf(arg, "hw:%d,%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that the `%d` notations mean that `hw:  3,   4` would be allowed as valid.  So would `hw:-34,+45`.  You can preclude those with a length check.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU C library supports [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). If you don't want to learn regular expressions, you can just repeatedly use `strncmp` as well as functions from the `ctype.h` header.

Comment: A full regular expression is a fairly big sledgehammer for a fairly small nut.  Certainly it would work, and if you're already using regular expressions would be sensible.